# Android LinearLayout weights switched

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-layout-weight

I have som nestd layouts, and nested weights (don't know, if source of problem, just saying), and in the lowest layer, my weights are switched up.

Meaning that TextView has weight 1, and ImageView has weight 2, and it does look correct in the preview, but when I build it, it's switched, and the TextView has weight 2, and the ImageView has weight 1.

Here's my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.firstproject.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/profile_pic"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="@string/about"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:background="#77ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/arduino_cropped"
        android:layout_below="@id/header">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Hobbies"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#77ffffff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
             <!-- This is where the problem lies -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="@string/coding"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:background="#77ffffff" />

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/code"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scaleType="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/dancing"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:background="#77ffffff" />

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/dance"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is a screenshot from the device:
[image: screenshot from the device]

This is a screenshot from the layout manager:
[image: screenshot from the layout manager]

Comment: ICYM the sum of weight should be 1, so use the float number which desire your heart

Comment: Add the screen shot for both..how you want and how you getting..

Comment: @AnilPrajapati I uploaded two pictures, one from the device, and one from the layout manager. You can see, that they are entirely switched up.